# Convert PS (Post Script) File In to Word Using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, postscript

A Question in my mind Is it possible to convert Postscript(PS) File Into Word(doc) file using Asp.Net? If Yes then how can we resolve it via C# Code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool which will convert PostScript to word. Not only that, but you certainly can't reliably do anything except render the whole thing to an image, and isert that as a graphic.

Up to a point you can extract text, what is it you actually want to do ?

Comment: thanx for reply Kens and i actually want extract complete text with graphics,images etc into word..

Comment: I suspect your best bet will be to convert to PDF and then use a PDF tool to convert to Word. I don't know of anything which will do it in one step. I have no idea if there are any tools which will preserve vector linework and bitmap images as well though.